# how to combine multiple *argv into a char* type messge

Tags: c, argv

I wrote a TCP socket client program which allows user to input the IP, port, and message as arguments.

It is like:

```
./a.out 127.0.0.1 555 test message
```

My question is, how to combine "test" (`argv[3]`) and "message" (`argv[4]`) and more into a `char *message`?

Comment: just a random text for testing, it could be any words like: finally done

Comment: so if test is just a string, what does test(argv[3]) mean?

Comment: that was a mistake, it corrected now.

Answer (score 9):

What you want to do is actually this:

```
/a.out 127.0.0.1 555 "test message"
```

By putting quotes around the message, argv[3] will contain the full message. Then you don't have to bother concatenating the arguments together.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to get the length of your `argv` strings that you want to combine.  Create a char array of that size, and then copy the strings over, using `strcpy` (preferably the secure version).

Comment: Don't forget to add room in the output char array for spaces.

Comment: .. and to write spaces between the strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strlen` to get the lengths of the strings, then allocate a buffer of the appropriate size and use `sprintf` or `strcpy` to fill it with your formatted data.

But as Kurtis says, if all you want to do is pass a string containing spaces to your program, then that’s the concern of the shell, not your program. On Unix you should use single quotes (`'`), and on Windows you can use double quotes (`"`).

Comment: On windows you can also use the `GetCommandLine` API that returns you the whole unparsed command line string.